# How to create a multi-database transaction in Java?

Tags: java, spring, oracle, hibernate, jndi

**Scenario:**

- DB1 and DB2 each have a table "T1"
- When I call the insert(..) method on my service, I need both database tables to to be updated.
- If an update fails on one of the databases, they both need to ROLLBACK.

**Looking into:**

- JTA Distributed Transactions - Haven't had much luck w/ this yet.

***Service Call:***

```java
Service.update(id, value);
```

***Service Implementation Pseudo-code:***

```java
@Transactional(value="twoDBTransactionManager")
public class Service {
    TwoDBTransMgr tm = new TwoDBTransMgr(DB1, DB2);

    /** Option #1 **/
    public void updateBoth(id, value) {
        tm.updateBothAndCommit(id, value);
    }

    /** Option #2 **/
    public void update(id, value) {
        tm.updateDB1(id, value);
        tm.updateDB2(id, value);
        tm.commitBoth();
    }
```

**Application Context**

```xml
<jee:jndi-lookup id="db1" jndi-name="jdbc/db1" resource-ref="true" proxy-interface="javax.sql.DataSource"/>
<jee:jndi-lookup id="db2" jndi-name="jdbc/db2" resource-ref="true" proxy-interface="javax.sql.DataSource"/>
```

**Technologies:**

Oracle 12c, Java 6, Spring, Maven, Hibernate, JNDI

**PL/SQL Equivalent Solution:**

```sql
DECLARE
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO t1@TESTLINK (val) VALUES ('DB LINK');
  INSERT INTO t1 (val) VALUES ('NO DB LINK');
  COMMIT;
EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
  ROLLBACK;
  RAISE;
END;
/
```

Comment: You need an XA distributed transaction for that.

Comment: The two databases are not the same, just a few of the tables.

Comment: I didn't say anything about them being the same.

Comment: My bad, mixed up your response w/ a conversation i was having w/ someone else earlier.

Comment: What's the trick with all these _w/_? :) Why don't you write the word _with_?

Comment: habit: w/ = with w/out = without. Not sure where I picked it up, but I've been writhing it that way for quite some time.

Answer (score 0):

I did the same research on this topic before. Seems that there is no straight forward approach to achieve.

If DB1 and DB2 are using same DB system (let's say oracle). I think it's better to use DB Link to do this.

That mean, you use single datasource to access tables at both DB.

Comment: Yeah, that's the easiest way to do that and that is what I am currently doing (see PL/SQL Equivalent Solution section). While ultimately, I think that is the best solution, there are times when a DB link is not a possibility (due to client requirements, for example). So i was curious about how you would do this in Java, under those conditions.

Answer (score 0):

i think message may be a way to solve this.let's say, A,B are two DB connection. they can't know each other. we need another compoment to communicate.

let's  say:  before transaction, A,B send a msg to C, and do some operation, then send a msg to c to tell either ok or not. then C send a msg to A,B  which is define the transaction commit or rollback.

just like:

Start:

A----> C

B----> C

send a msg to C,tell C to help Observe the operator

operate:

A: do some operation,than

A ---> C tell C operate success or fail

B: do some operation,than

B ---> C tell C operate success or fail

A,B hold, after send a msg to C,waiting for the singal form C

end:

C---> A

C---> B

tell A,B, to commit or rollback

Comment: This looks like a restating of my request, not an actual solution. But that may just be because "message" is such a common word. Are you referring to a specific framework?